# When rendering a page in HTML skip lines that contain certain text

Tags: html, pdf

Is there any way to stop HTML rendering a line based on keywords? So as the webpage or PDF is rendering using HTML, if the data used to render a line includes a particular keyword, that line is skipped?

Current code:

```
                    <!-- Begin Item Invoice Line Items -->
                    <div class="item-invoice items">
                        <table class="list">
                            <tr class="header">
                                <th class="code">Code</th>
                                <th class="description">Description</th>
                                <th class="qty">Qty</th>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Begin Item Invoice Line Item -->
                            <tr class="item">
                                <td class="code">{LineItem.Item.Code}</td>
                                <td class="description">{LineItem.Item.Description}</td>
                                <td class="qty">{LineItem.Quantity}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- End Item Invoice Line Item -->
```

For example, is it possible to stop the code rendering any line item that contains the keyword "Freight"?

I've tried Googling, but if it's possible I'm using the incorrect keywords and the results aren't helpful. Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you just using HTML or any other language to generate this code? If you're using JS to generate the td cells you can use JS to check and return only it matches your criteria.

Comment: Hello Monish, only CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that if you have array of words

```
// loop to your array with for loop
for(let i = 0; i<=words.length - 1; i++) {
   if(words[i].word === 'Freight') // if words uquals freight
   break // your code will break here

   // write what you want to happen before break here
}
```

Comment: Hello Giorgi, where in my code snippet should I insert your loop?

Comment: where you are render list from pdf

Comment: Thanks, still can't make it work but thinking it's because it's HTML only (doesn't support JS)